# How do I prevent AVG from pausing my goLang execution?

Tags: go, antivirus

Disclaimer: Isn't necessarily a programming question, more like a how to use avg whilst programming question...

So I don't just want to turn my antivirus off, but I don't want to have to click abort every time I run something.

Quick aside I just got golang setup on windows for the first time after using Ubuntu for a while (thinking I'll get on debian when I stand up my Linux partition again, at least that's what I ear all the cool kids are doing...) but yeah...

Any advice would be appreciated!

[image: go run helloworld.go]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `C:\User\Kevin\Desktop\go` to AVG exclusion list.

Answer (score 3):

You have to exclude `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\go-*`.

Comment: This ended up being the solution that I needed when dealing with AVG. Thanks!